# Singular series in the circle method

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Counting primes by circle method $$\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n_0=1}^{N}e^{2\pi ian_0}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\Lambda (n)e^{-2\pi ian}da$$  I tried to find the main term by looking at major arcs, but the singular series doesn't seem to behave in a way that gives the main term as in second Chebyshev function $\Psi(N)=N+o(N)$.
Is it possible to get the main term by considering major arcs? Or at least where it can be located and what to consider?

Comment: Are the two sums supposed to be independent of each other or are they nested? In the latter case, the summation indices should not be the same in them.

Comment: This will eventually work - it is just the major arc near the origin which is relevant (with the bulk of the contribution coming from the region $a = O(1/N)$ or $a = 1-O(1/N)$), but it is rather circular, since to estimate $\sum_{n=1}^N \Lambda(n) e^{-2\pi i an}$ for such values of $a$ requires a version of the prime number theorem with reasonably good error terms in the first place.